# Quickbooks PHP error: "No data to exchange for this application. Job ending."

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

We are encountering an issue while Import but are unable to identify the root cause.

Message:
No data exchange required

Description:
No data to exchange for this application. Job ending.

`code`

require_once qb/docs/example_app_web_connector/functions.php';

$map = array(
QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_SALESORDER => array( '_quickbooks_customer_add_request', '_quickbooks_customer_add_response' ),
);

$errmap = array('*' => '_quickbooks_error_catchall',);

$hooks = array();

$log_level = QB_LOG_DEVELOP;

$soapserver = QB_SOAPSERVER;

$soap_options = array();

$handler_options = array('deny_concurrent_logins' => false,);

$driver_options = array();

$callback_options = array();

$Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level, $soapserver, QB_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options, $driver_options, $callback_options);
$response = $Server->handle(true, true);

`code`